# Flutter: show dialog by provider library

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

In my project i want to use provider library.In my page i have a grid list of icon,when user clicked on each icon i will show a dialog.

In my dialog i have Text Field and a button widgets. When user fill the Text Field and clicked on a button i want to fetch some data from my web service and after fetching i want to show again these data on other Alert dialog in my page.

How can i handle that situation by provider?

```
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return myCustomNumberDialog(
        headerTitle: :"Send Data",
        buttonTitle: "Search Data",
        onConfirmClicked: (input) { //a button action when user tap on it, It send request to api
        // when data fetched from service show other dialog
        },
      );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
onConfirmClicked: (input) { 
  Provider.of<Model>(context, listen: false)
            .callMethod().then((response) {
           // Based on the the response coming from Provider, decide functionaliy. 
              Navigator.of(context).pop();   // pop current dialog
              // show new dialog from here.
        }),
   }
```

Comment: I have a question,How can i show loading dialog when user is waiting to arrive data ?@jitsm555

Comment: Ask another question @sayreskabir for that problem, and show your code according to that. People will be able to help you more like in this case. Share your link here to the question. We will help you :)